# Upload Files Into Database and check the database value in the table exist or not

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database, file-upload

I need to make form that upload sql file or csv file into the database.
If the user upload example.sql, all the data will upload into the database.
I need to check the database and the table, if the value in the table exist, the value will not insert into the table of database. If does not exist, it will upload into the table of database. I dont want the data that been uploaded duplicate with the existing data in the table

Here is my **Php that for upload into my database** called ituser_sales and the table called site_sales.

```
if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
    $file = $_FILES['file'];

    //file properties
    $file_name = $file['name'];
    $file_tmp = $file['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $file['size'];
    $file_error = $file['error'];

    //extension
    $file_ext = explode('.', $file_name);
    $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));
    $actionstatus = "<center><div class=\"alert alert-success\" style=\"max-width: 250px;\">
    <button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\">&times;</button>
    User Update Successful.
    </div></center>";

    $allowed = array('csv', 'sql', 'txt');

    if (in_array($file_ext, $allowed)){
        if($file_error === 0){
            if ($file_size <= 1000000){
                $file_name_new = uniqid('', true) . '.' . $file_ext;
                $file_destination = 'uploads/'.$file_name_new;

                if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination)){
                    **$query ="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$file_destination."' INTO TABLE site_sales
                    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
                    IGNORE 1 LINES;**";
                    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
                    if ($result){
                        echo $actionstatus;
                        echo "Your file name will be <h4>$file_name_new</h4>";
                    } else {
                        echo '<br><button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button><br><br>';
                        echo '<script>
                        function goBack() {
                        window.history.back();
                        }
                        </script>';
                        die (mysqli_error());
                        include("includes/footer.php");

                    }

                }
            }
        }
    } else{
        echo "<br>Your file is either none of these extensions (.$allowed[0], .$allowed[1], .$allowed[2]) <br>";
        echo '<br><button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button><br>';
        echo '<script>
        function goBack() {
        window.history.back();
        }
        </script>';
        die (mysqli_error($con));
        include("includes/footer.php");
    }
}
```

I need to change that query to perform checking for the value in the table.
Here is my example of data that need to be upload:

sales_id,storenumber,busidate,NETSALES,tax,disc_amt,SKVOC,NETAMT,TRNCNT
,1,2018-01-01,9468.82,560.96,0,920,8548.82,212

**This data in the example.sql**

[here is the example in the database (ituser_sales), table (site_sales) after upload the sql file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCVmX.jpg)
[Here is the duplicate example if i upload again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlKvs.jpg)

If the value exist, the data will not duplicate the exist data. 
the query will read next line (new data) to check it exist or not until the last of data in sql file

any idea with this ?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Is any of that a unique ID?  Two people could go to the same store on the same day and buy the same thing.

Comment: There is no buy same thing and same day. This is for user (Admin Department, Operation Department), it will upload some data (sql file) then i need to check if the value in the table exist or not. If exist, it will not duplicate, if not exist, the value will insert into the table. Sorry im still newbie. hope u can help :)

Comment: One approach is to copy into a temp table, read each row, see if each row is already in the real table, if no then insert that row.

Comment: can you be more specific for the code query? i still cant understood about this . much appreciate for your help